# MsgBox Does Not Appear When Passed RecordCount Property

Tags: ms-access, vba, msgbox

**Edit:** The issue was `On Error Resume Next` suppressing the errors in `OpenRecordset`, leaving the Variant set to Nothing. `OpenRecordset` failed due to misspelled column names, and specifying *Type* when *Type* is determined by default by proxy of being a linked table.

**Solution**: Comment out/remove `On Error Resume Next` to raise errors. Correct spelling errors in column names. Do not specify type (leave position blank) when Querying from Linked table (*Type* is automatically Dynaset for querys from linked tables.

In a particular section of code, I am trying to display the number of records in a recordset (mostly for debugging purposes). I stumbled across what I believe to be a unique error. The Code is as follows:

```
specsVariableTempTableName = "specs_variable_" & CStr(Me.OpFormOpRecordID) & "_temp"

specItemsQuery = "SELECT [Item], [Document #], [Item Description], [SubItems], [Attribute], [Spec Characteristics] FROM [tbl_forms] WHERE [Document #] = '" & Me![Form #] & "' AND [Part #] = '" & Me![Part Number] & "';"

Set db_source = CurrentDb

If IsNull(DLookup("Name", "MSysObjects", "Name='" & specsVariableTempTableName & "' And Type In (1,4,6)")) Then
        'Check for existing temporary spec table
        'Create one if not
        MsgBox ("No temporary table " & specsVariableTempTableName)
        Set specItemsRecordSet = db_source.OpenRecordset(specItemsQuery, , dbFailOnError).Clone

        MsgBox (specItemsRecordSet.RecordCount & " Records")
        MsgBox ("What the f***")


        If Not (specItemsRecordSet.EOF And specItemsRecordSet.BOF) Then
            'If the result set is not empty, go to first entry
            specItemsRecordSet.MoveFirst
            With specItemsRecordSet
                MsgBox (.RecordCount)
            End With
        Else
            MsgBox ("No Specs found for given part number and document number")
        End If


        db_source.Execute "SELECT [Document #], [Part #], [ParentItem], [SubItem], [Nominal], [LSL], [USL], [UOM] INTO " & specsVariableTempTableName & " FROM [Specs_Variable] WHERE (([Specs_Variable]![Document #] = '" & Me![Form #] & "') AND ([Specs_Variable]![Part #] = '" & Me![Part Number] & "'));", dbFailOnError
    End If
```

The line in-question is MsgBox(specItemsRecordSet.RecordCount & " Records"). The MsgBox lines before and after this line display a MsgBox and I have to click OK to close it. However, this particular line displays no MsgBox, the code does not pause, it simply continues to the next line as if the code weren't there at all.

I have tried to rename the tables in the query, I have tried .MoveLast before invoking .RecordCount. Even the MsgBox in the WITH block does not show. I would expect that if the query returned no results that I would get a 0, Null, or an Error when trying to show in MsgBox but that the MsgBox would still show and require user action to continue.

Comment: I'd try a compact and repair. This sounds more like a VBA project corruption thing than a code issue.

Comment: I'd start with adding `Option Explicit` at the top of your module, and removing _all_ parentheses around  the arguments for all sub or function calls that don't return an argument (all those msgbox calls). Your VBA is borderline invalid.

Comment: Have you tried setting a break point and stepping through the code?

Comment: I feel that the specItemsRecordSet is not open.  For example from the MSDN:     Dim dbsNorthwind As Database / 
     Dim rstEmployees As Recordset  /
     
     Set dbsNorthwind = OpenDatabase("Northwind.mdb")  / 
     
     With dbsNorthwindSet rstEmployees = .OpenRecordset("Employees") / I dont think your recordset is properly brought up to speed. / to prove this you could place an If ERROR in front of your message box, if it pops, then VBA is trying to help you but making it hard for you to troubleshoot by suppressing.

Comment: Set dbsNorthwind = OpenDatabase("Northwind.mdb") 
     
 
       Set arstProducts(1) = dbsNorthwind.OpenRecordset( _ 
          "SELECT ProductName FROM Products " & _ 
          "ORDER BY ProductName", dbOpenSnapshot) 
     
       ' Create two clones of the original Recordset. 
       Set arstProducts(2) = arstProducts(1).Clone 
       Set arstProducts(3) = arstProducts(1).Clone / Perhaps you need an initial recordset before you can clone it . . . . .

Comment: As @ErikA notes, MsgBox should not use parens when used only to present a message to user and no input other than to close the box is needed from user. Should not use reserved words (Name, Type) as names for anything. Also should avoid spaces and punctuation/special characters (underscore only exception) in naming convention.

Comment: If you have `On Error Resume Next` in effect, and OpenRecordset fails, then the 2nd `MsgBox` will be skipped.

Comment: @TomRobinson I removed ```On Error Resume Next``` and identified the ```OpenRecordset``` method was erroring - exactly the case you suggested. That line is giving me an _Invalid Argument_ error but I can't figure out why. 

@Wookies-Will-Code I cut out the portion of code where I instantiated an empty recordset, and then used ```Set``` to declare it. I also would expect to invoke members and properties in-line so long as the returned object has those members. I have not had issues with this in other areas of my code but an innate understanding of VBA still eludes me.

Comment: I identified that one of the column names was misspelled. After correcting that error, the issue persists.

Comment: By removing the options dbOpenDynamic and dbFailOnError the issue goes away. More closely reading the dox for DAO.Database.OpenRecordset (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/database-openrecordset-method-dao) I found that VBA automatically creates the Recordset as a Dynaset if the source is a linked table. Indeed, tbl_forms is a linked table, and leaving the positional argument blank instead of specifying dbOpenDynamic or dbOpenDynaset corrects the issue